# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS force Detect One GPU

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, detect, xorg

I have **ASUS Laptop X53BR-SX013V** with 2 GPU:

1. **IGD: AMD Radeon HD 6320**
2. **DGD: AMD Radeon HD 7470M**

The first is compatible with **radeon** driver module, the second not and the Ati driver is not developed for **Ubuntu 16.04.2**.

Booting without **"radeon.modeset=0"** cause slow booting process (21 minutes) which stay hang for this time with message:

**"A start job is running for detect the avaiable GPUs and deal any system change".**

After this time the boot complete successfully, the hd6230 works with good graphic performance.

There is a way to force radeon module to detect only **AMD Radeon HD 6320** and ignore the other GPU?
Configuring **Xorg.conf** can be a correct way?

Note: With **"radeon.modeset=0"** or **nomodeset** the boot process is fast but the graphic is very poor

Thanks

Comment: Same problem with 18.04. Did you have solved it ?

Comment: Did you solve it ?